# Trying to learn ColdFusion but can't access Administrator

Tags: coldfusion, wamp

I installed WAMP and ColdFusion but when I go to http://localhost/cfide/administrator it gives a 404 error. CFML is displayed fine so the ColdFusion server must be running correctly.

I'm using WAMP ServerVersion 2.2 ColdFusion 9 and Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: did you try http://localhost/CFIDE/administrator ? the URL is case sensitive and the CFIDE-folder is uppercased.

Comment: does localhost/cfide/administrator/index.cfm work?

Comment: @Seybsen still 404 error

Comment: @Jason "The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error." and says file not found

Comment: @Jason "The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error." and says file not found

Comment: Is cfide/administrator/index.cfm actually there in the folder that localhost is mapped to?  If not, do you have a virtual directory to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Seybsen and Jason hit on the two most common reasons for not being able to hit the administrator.  Seeing as you're on Windows, it's unlikely to be case-sensitivity.  But not having index.cfm as a default document will be a problem.  You can add it to the http.conf:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex dex index.html index.cfm default.cfm
</IfModule>
```

If hitting the entire string including index.cfm doesn't work, then it's likely Mark's solution.  To elaborate, you'll need to check either the http.conf or the mod_jk.conf to make sure that the alias is there:

```
Alias /CFIDE "C:\[full path to CFIDE]\CFIDE"
<Directory "C:\[full path to CFIDE]\CFIDE">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

That alias should work for all virtual hosts as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check your httpd.conf file to make sure there is an alias for CFIDE (and remember it's case sensitive).  If you still can't make it work try running the connector script for apache found in cfusion9/bin ... or run wsconfig for a gui to try to hook it up. Also remember to run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Try your actual ipaddress incase your server settings have not setup localhost by default.

In windows - run CMD or Command Prompt...
Then ipconfig

U should get ur ipaddress...

Replace localhost with that IP address - I have had that problem in the past...

And then create a shortcut with proper address